# Open the redirection in a new window

Tags: javascript

I have a following script

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       location = 'http://example.com';
}, false );
</script>
```

How should I edit the script to open the example.com in a new window in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       var location = 'http://example.com';
window.open(location,"_blank");
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `window.open(url,'_blank')`

```
var win = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com' , '_blank');//Require quatations
        win.focus();
```

Comment: Sorry, where should I paste it?

Comment: paste it between your script tag and remove your code

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.open()`:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
       var hre= 'https://google.com';
       window.open(hre,"_blank");
}, false );
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Thanks, but my script is a part of Wordpress function (and placed in functions.php) so I can't change the script. All I need is to open the url in a new tab of the (!) current script.

Comment: Ok. 'wpcf7mailsent' was the id you are using in <button> or <a>.?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this function for url redirection in js after success

window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

Comment: Thanks, but my script is a part of Wordpress function (and placed in functions.php) so I can't change the script. All I need is to open the url in a new tab of the (!) current script.

Comment: In wordpress you can try to use this function may help you 
 - window.location.href = "http://www.your-url.com";

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open("url");

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
function call(){

       window.open('http://example.com');
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="call()"/>
```